# Parse.com Push Notifications target _User objectId

Tags: json, rest, push-notification, parse-platform

I have discovered today in the Push notification area of the dashboard, that you can send a push notification to a user by that _User objectId.  I'm assuming this is possible because I've created a Pointer from the installations to the user.  I'm just curious how that would look in JSON format so that I can plug it into the REST API www.parse.com/1/push call.  Unfortunately there is no JSON preview provided.

```
{"user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"censored objectId"},"data":"{"alert":"test message"} }
```

That's what I've tried but I'm still learning JSON

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax

{"data":{"alert":"Message to send"},"where":{"user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"The objectId"} } }